# Combine columns A, B element by element into list-column of ranges from the elements of A and B

Tags: r, list, data.table, range

I am trying to write R code, preferably data.table, to generate the last column (`my_wanted_col`) from the information in columns `A` and `B`

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(A=c(1,2,3),
                B=c(5,6,7),
                my_wanted_col=list(1:5,2:6,3:7)
                )
```

That is, create a column that is a list of ranges. In each row the range is created by combining the cell in A with the cell in B (`cellA:cellB`).
The actual data has millions of observations, but the above example reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
library(data.table)
d[, my_wanted_col := Map(`:`, A, B)]
d

#   A B my_wanted_col
#1: 1 5     1,2,3,4,5
#2: 2 6     2,3,4,5,6
#3: 3 7     3,4,5,6,7
```

**data**

```
d <- data.table(A=c(1,2,3),B=c(5,6, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `by` as the sequence of rows and then just do a sequence from A to B

```
d[,   my_wanted_col := .(list(A:B)), by = 1:nrow(d)]
d
#   A B my_wanted_col
#1: 1 5     1,2,3,4,5
#2: 2 6     2,3,4,5,6
#3: 3 7     3,4,5,6,7
```

#### data

```
d <- data.table(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(5,6, 7))
```

Comment: tks. This time however the solution you proposed is much slower. This took 900s vs 30s for @Ronak_Shah `s solution above.

Comment: @LucasMation i think the grouping would slow that